# How to keep Illustrator Scripts handy?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, plugin, file-management

I have bunch of task which should be run simultaneously, but i have to click every time

> files > script > My scripts

Is there any way to keep all script handly like other properties available on right side menu or i have to do it manually every time?

[image: Image Example]

Comment: You can drag and drop a script file on illustrator causing it to run. This way you can just have a file browser/ webpage pointing to the local files hanging around. Drag and drop multople scrips and it executes them in order. You can also make actions do this, then you have the scripts in action palette (though there is a bug in older illus in loading order so you need to reload the actions after startup)

Answer (score 3):

There is a script named ScriptPanel_2.

It creates a panel with all the scripts inside the script folder or you can load any folder you want.

Just double click a script to run it.

You can download here: https://github.com/Silly-V/Adobe-Illustrator/blob/master/Script%20Panel%202/ScriptPanel_2.jsx

Reference image:

[image]

Also, there is a plugin named Jsx Launcher.

This plugin have buttons, then you can run a script with just one click.

You can find it here: https://exchange.adobe.com/creativecloud.details.12096.jsx-launcher.html

[image]

Comment: I hope it works for CC19, last time i checked , it's not compatible

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with scripting, but you probably could write a very basic new script that would run all the scripts you need, one after another:

```
$.evalFile("pathToMyFile/script1.jsx");
$.evalFile("pathToMyFile/script2.jsx");
$.evalFile("pathToMyFile/script3.jsx");
```

Another possible way is to record an action:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-actions.html

Comment: There was a bug in Illustrator when it was losing script names in Actions between restarts. Don't know if that was fixed in the latest versions though :/